# How to get d3 shape constructors to return the type string properly in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, d3.js

I am really stuck on how to work with @types/d3 properly. All the return types are really confusing and even console.logging is not helping.

Essentially when I call the arc() construct I get an error that: An argument for 'd' was not provided. But when I console.log it only returns the proper path string and not an error or invalid value.

I can't seem to find what to put as the argument as the d  value in the constructor. Also, a lot of js code I've seen doesn't have any input, what specific reason does typescript need to have an additional value?

```js
const Test = () => {
      // ...........
     // causes error if mArc is not mArc: any
     const mArc = arc() // how to not force any as a type here
        .innerRadius(radius)
        .outerRadius(width + radius)
        .startAngle(Math.PI / 2)
        .endAngle((Math.PI * 3) / 2)
      
     console.log(mArc()); // returns a string...
     // but typescript throws an error, An argument for 'd' was not provided.
     return <path d={mArc()} />;
      
}
```

Sorry, I may not be understanding this software engineering correctly. When I look in the types.d file for d3-shape, it says no definition found for 'Datum', which is the type 'd' is supposed to be

Comment: Try `const arcPath = mAr();` then `return <path d={arcPath} />`. Does it help?

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work as mAr(); has an error and arcPath is of the type never.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proper answer:

```js
const Test = () => {
     const mArc = arc<void, void>()
        .innerRadius(radius)
        .outerRadius(width + radius)
        .startAngle(Math.PI / 2)
        .endAngle((Math.PI * 3) / 2)
      
     console.log(mArc());
     return <path d={mArc() || ""} />;
      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also struggling with getting the type safety working with d3. There are two methods to use the [arc](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#arc) method, via chaining (which seems to be the most popular) or via an object. It doesn't seem like the d3 type definitions work with (fully) chaining. Calling your mArc() function with no arguments is the issue (although it works).

One caviate is that cornerRadius doesn't seem to be in the type definition for the object (padAngle does work), however it can be set on your mArc function via chaining.

The following snippet will work with no type errors.

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
const Test = () => {

  const radius = 100;
  const width = 5;

  const mArc = d3.arc();

  return (
    <path
      d={
        mArc({
          innerRadius: radius,
          outerRadius: width + radius,
          startAngle: Math.PI / 2,
          endAngle: (Math.PI * 3) / 2,
        }) || ""
      }
    />
  );
};
```